# java regex matching ip address and port number as captured groups

Tags: java, regex, ip-address, port-number

could please anybody tell me what is wrong with this regexp ?

```
((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\\:([0-9]{2,5})
```

for matching this: assfasfas>192.168.1.1:8080192.168.222.43:8286

I need 192.168.1.1 and 8080 to be captured groups

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unless you *really, really* have to do IP adress *validation*, as well, I suggest you simplify the regular expression, because this beast is far too complex for only matching "IP part" and "port part". My suggestion would be

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})
```

Groups 1 and 2 will hold IP and port, respectively. And the above is already more complex that it needs to be, IMHO even something as simple as this would be enough:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):(\d+)
```

Note that double backslashes are are requirement of Java strings, not of regex, so I left them out.

Comment: But compiler says: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: It was because of I declared it as String, sorry

Comment: As I said, Java strings require the backslash to be escaped. So a `\d` in regex will be a `\\d` in a Java string.