# How can I restrict input to only periods, numbers and semicolons in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation, input, restrict

I want to restrict what characters a user can type in an input text field such that they can only type in numbers and periods and colons. So if they type anything else, it won't show up or register. This is for IP addresses for example: 10.200.66.106:8888

How can I achieve this in jQuery?

I've written a little example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xMxs/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
            <p>IP Address:</p>
        <p class="edit">2323</p>
    </div>
<div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').editable('ipaddress/update',{ 
     type      : 'textarea',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'OK',        
     tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
 });
```

});

Comment: possible duplicate of [java regex matching ip address and port number as captured groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908740/java-regex-matching-ip-address-and-port-number-as-captured-groups)

Comment: _"and semicolons...for example: 10.200.66.106:8888"_ - So you mean colons, not semicolons?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove not-allowed characters:

```
<input id="ip" type="text" />



$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#ip').keyup(function() { 
        var el = $(this),
            val = el.val();

         el.val(val.replace(/[^\d\.]/gi, ""));
     }).blur(function() {
         $(this).keyup();
     });
 });
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xMxs/1/)

But there are better ways, you can for example completely "block" the entering of unwanted characters. And remember, you can easily avoid these restrictions when no server-side validation is being done.

Also, you might want to checkout the [html5 attribute pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) which, as the context suggests, only works for html5 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [alphanumeric plugin](http://www.shiguenori.com/material/alphanumeric/) to do that.
Add some class to your element.

```
$(".myclass").numeric({allow:"."});
```

Comment: Note that the alphanumeric plugin that you link to doesn't really work. That is, it does not stop the user from entering invalid characters via clipboard paste or drag'n'drop.

Comment: i'm using the plugin right now and it just restricts the user from copying and pasting

Comment: @JohnathanAu - it doesn't restrict pasting, it just disables the context menu, so you can still paste via the Edit menu or keyboard.